# Problema con fechas Java / Linux

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Tengo un problema con las fechas, una aplicación Spring desplegada en Tomcat. Cuando recupero los datos de los formularios, se almacenan de forma correcta en la base de datos en Windows. Cuando paso la aplicación a Linux, se almacena la misma fecha pero un día menos. El problema está en Spring, dado que lo que llega a la base de datos es la fecha modificada. Esta fecha no se modifica en ningún paso de forma explícita, de hecho en Windows funciona correctamente la misma aplicación.

¿Alguien le pasó o tiene idea donde se pierde ese día?

Comment: Parece un tema de zona horaria. ¿Puedes verificar las zonas horarias de ambos servidores, Windows y Linux? Adicional, en tu servidor linux, ejecuta el comando `date` para ver si la fecha en la que está configurada es la misma que la fecha de tu servidor Windows.

Comment: Ya comprobé que la fecha del servidor fuera la correcta. `Windows`tiene zona horaria Española, el `Linux` Uruguaya en un server en USA (remoto) `$ date
Fri Oct 14 12:39:05 UYT 2016`

Comment: Allí está la causa de tu problema. Configura o solicita que ambos servidores estén con la misma zona horaria.

Answer (score 2):

POr si te sirve te pongo este código que lo que hace es Convertir fecha y hora entre zonas horarias o timezones, muy lo que necesitas.

```
public class TimeZoneCambio {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    inFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Guatemala"));
    Date purchaseDate = new Date();

    System.out.println("Fecha/Hora Original");
    System.out.println(inFormat.format(purchaseDate));

    DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    outFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Spain"));

    System.out.println("Misma Fecha/Hora en España");
    System.out.println(outFormat.format(purchaseDate));

  }
}
```

la salida del programa será así,

Fecha/Hora Original

2013-04-19 22:54:51

Misma Fecha/Hora en España

ESpero que lo puedas usar.
2013-04-20 04:54:51

Answer (score 1):

Por la información que das pueden ser varios factores, pero la causa es la misma. Si usas `java.lang.Date` para representar una fecha sin marca de tiempo, este toma las 00:00 horas del día indicado. En cuánto dicha fecha es representada en un timezone menor, ocurre el fenómeno que comentas.

La solución puede estar en configurar bien los servidores para igualar la configuración de timezone, o al mostrar la fecha en cliente configurar el componente de salida para formatear la fecha con timezone, por ejemplo en JSF puedes aplicar un formateador.

También puedes considerar utilizar en bbdd tipos date o time con información de timezone.

Comment: El problema es que a mi socio que está en Uruguay le pasa lo mismo, y su zona horaria es la misma que la del servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Por la descripción del problema y lo que veo en comentarios, la razón es de una configuración diferente en la zona horaria de los servidores. Configura o solicita que ambos servidores estén con la misma zona horaria.

En caso que no se pueda cambiar la configuración de zona horaria en tu servidor Linux (lo cual sería extraño), puedes hacer el cambio a nivel de aplicación en Java, en la manera como se inicia la aplicación. Basado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2493805/1065197), solo tendrías que agregar un parámetro al ejecutar la JVM:

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Madrid
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambié todos los campos en los beans a `String`para no utilizar `Date` al recuperar los datos de los formularios, dado que date en MySQL se puede insertar desde String, conviertiendo el String del formato de la vista al formato de la base de datos con:

```
private String formatDate (String date, String initDateFormat, String endDateFormat) {
    String parsedDate = null;
    try {
        java.util.Date initDate = new SimpleDateFormat(initDateFormat).parse(date);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(endDateFormat);
        parsedDate = formatter.format(initDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return parsedDate;
}
```

Comment: En realidad esto resuelve el problema parcialmente puesto que `SimpleDateFormat` usa por defecto el `TimeZone` que obtiene del OS.